# Show HTML element in NextJS

Tags: javascript, html, next.js, fastapi

I have an api that returns an html (figure converted in html) and I'd like to show this html in my nextjs page but I dont know how.
This is my api code:

```
@router.get("/graph/{id_file}", name="Return the graph obtained")
async def create_graph(id_file: str):
        data = HAR.preparaDatos(id_file)
        dataFinal = HAR.dataYprediccion(data, 'routes/modelo.h5')
        fig = px.scatter(dataFinal, x=dataFinal['dateTimes'], y=dataFinal['nameActivities'])
        ht=fig.to_html()
        
        return HTMLResponse(ht)
```

And It returns this graph (in html):
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZNP4.png)

And this is my code in nextJS where I'm trying to show this graph:

```
<div className="grid">
            <p className="description">
              In this graph you can see the activity performed.
            </p>
            {isLoading && <p className="loading">Loading graph...</p>}
            <p className="graph">
                <script src={`http://127.0.0.1:8000/showGraph/graph/${id}`} />
            </p>
```

But I can't finally see the graph on my page, does anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: Is the return type an image? If so, you are not telling the browser to render an image anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Reacts *dangerouslySetInnerHTML* to render HTML into an element.
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: yourHTML}} />
```